# Node Express server returning different REST response depending on if running inside Docker container or from source

Tags: docker, express

This is a most bizarre problem I've faced recently, which I've narrowed down to the title and have no idea where to turn to next.

I have a Node JS Express server, that returns a relatively straight forward set of HTTP REST JSON response.

When I run the server from source (npm run dev), and query it via API call (or browser), I receive an accurate response (Not sure that it matters, but it is an array of length 5)

When I run the exact same set of code in a Docker container, the server returns the same array minus one row, so 4 items.

What in the earth could cause that?

Dockerfile here:

```
FROM node:17.6 as ts-compiler
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

FROM node:17.6 as ts-remover
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY --from=ts-compiler /usr/app/package*.json ./
COPY --from=ts-compiler /usr/app/build ./src
RUN npm install --only=production

FROM node:17.6-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY --from=ts-remover /usr/app ./
USER 1000
CMD ["src/server.js"]
```

I tried running it from Source, refreshing cache, restarting server, removing the Docker image completely and re-building, building & running Docker image via new tag, adding logging in my server to further debug

Answer (score 0):

Omg.

The DATE.

I have a database query that fetches data relative to the current DATE.

On my computer:

```
$ date
Mon  8 May 2023 22:23:34 EDT
```

From within the Docker container:

```
/usr/app $ date
Tue May  9 02:23:39 UTC 2023
```

*cries*